# VLC installation on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, vlc

I tried to install VLC on my Ubuntu 17.10 but as you can see the response of terminal:

[image: got problem installing vlc on ubuntu 17.10]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: There is a huge picture with a bit of tiny text in it. Can't you just copy/paste the text itself?

Comment: try repeating your `sudo snap install vlc` command, it looks like maybe a temporary failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download VLC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489302/how-to-download-vlc)

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get vlc
```

is not a valid command, it should be

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

To install the snap version run

```
snap install vlc
```

Comment: Any reason why OP's first line = `sudo snap install vlc` should have failed? (I don't use snap packages myself.)

Comment: @Dɑvïd I don't either, maybe a temporary connection issue?